# Bean Post Processor implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot

According to Spring Boot docs

> An ApplicationContext can autodetect BeanPostProcessor beans in its
>   bean definitions and apply those post-processors to any beans
>   subsequently created

I have created a custom bean post processor class in the main class package, but it is not working.Here is the code.

```
public class DataBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, Ordered {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass()).info("Before Processing- " + beanName);
        return bean;
    }
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass()).info("After Processing- " + beanName);
        return bean;
    }


    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: You do need to annotate it with `@Component` for Spring to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As daniu said in the comment you must add @Component

```
@Component
public class DataBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, Ordered {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass()).info("Before Processing- " + beanName);
        return bean;
    }
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass()).info("After Processing- " + beanName);
        return bean;
    }


    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be the issue, but there's not enough information here to say for sure.

Comment: No but this is my answer based on the question. If it doesn't work he can come back